# How to refresh record after an update with a SP

Tags: c#, data-binding, insert

I am dealing with the following problem: 
I use a MSSQL Stored Procedure for displaying my data in a DataGridView. The Update and Insert Commands work, but there is one problem:

On inserting a new Row, the auto-numbered primary key isn't send back to my DataAdaptar. So the insertion is successfull in the database, but the PK is left blank in the DataGridView.
I allready tried some codes like:

```
    private void _rowUpdated(object sender, SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == UpdateStatus.Continue && e.StatementType == StatementType.Insert)
        {
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY FROM " + e.Row.Table.TableName;

            DataRow r = dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1];
            r.ItemArray[0] = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            //r.SetModified(); --> err?
            r.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }
```

on the DataAdapter, but nothing seems to work. All the SQL commands work fine.

When I refresh the data in the DataGridView, everyting is perfect. But the problem with this is, that the sort order and column width are adjusted. And that isn't what I want.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Looking forward for the solutions!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer and wanted to share it:

```
dt.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(_update_fields);


    private void _update_fields(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Action == DataRowAction.Add)
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('" + e.Row.Table.TableName + "')";
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][0] = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) + 1;
                dt.AcceptChanges();
                conn.Close();
            }
            adapt.Update(dt);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Hope it will save you some time! :)

Gr
VeeWee

Answer (score 0):

Since the connection to sql server has terminated so @@identity will become null and hence you are getting null value.

You cannot use scope_identity() here since its scope is limited to the place i.e. procedure in your case where it is called.

ident_current() always returns last identity value for the table that you specified.
It might not work correct in case of replication

```
Update your commandText to ="Select ident_current("+e.Row.Table.TableName+")"
```

Here are the results of using various techniques of retrieving identity value.
Replace dbo.M_PatientEntry with your table name

```
select ident_current('dbo.M_PatientEntry')
---------------------------------------
13

select @@identity from dbo.M_PatientEntry    
---------------------------------------
NULL
NULL

select scope_identity()    
---------------------------------------
NULL

select scope_identity() from dbo.M_PatientEntry    
---------------------------------------
NULL
NULL
```

Also try avoiding @@Identity rather use scope_identity() or ident_current
@@identity will give you incremented value of trigger table result if you are using trigger on the same table where insertion is going on.

[see this documentation](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Hello,
I tested the code like this:

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('" + e.Row.Table.TableName + "')";
var res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
Debug.WriteLine("RESULTS:" + res);

It gave the same result as with my query. But you are right, its better to use this sql function. But the problem still exists: The PK field is left empty. I guess the datarow isn't saved in the function. But all the actions I use (Update, AcceptChanges, ..) result in an infinite loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: @VeeWee: Why not put a breakpoint at cmd.ExecuteScalar() and check what value it gives. Try to check its result on immediate window (Alt+Ctrl+I) in VS.Net. Just copy paste this `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` and check what you are getting. Try the same query on sql server. It will give you desired result. I cant say much about working on disconnected architecture and hence cant help you much with issues related to it.

Comment: @VeeWee: Is this event row_updated() running under a loop ? What does this means **"all the actions I use (Update, AcceptChanges, ..) result in an infinite loop"**

Comment: Indeed, I should have used breakpoints. The result of the function is fine. When I take a closer look, I see that the exact row is selected, but that the first column isn't filled with the query result. Instead there is a System.DBNull value. It looks like the row is blocked? I think I cannot just change the insertCommand because I want to make 1 component for multiple tables, so the name of the PK is unknown.

Comment: I don't think its running in a loop. At least I didn't put it in a loop... When I try the following stuff: dt.AcceptChanges or adapt.Update(); The program starts to add rows untill I get an infinity loop error.

Comment: in that case you can modify your query little bit to `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('" + e.Row.Table.TableName + "' as PK)";` now u can get column name as PK

Comment: since this query returns object type so you must check `if(result.GetType()==DBNull.Value)` DBNull hence initialize value to Null. Moreover DBNull and Null are two different entities and you cannot initialize  an object with DBNull because DBNull is a different class object System.DBNull and null is a different entity

Comment: No, I meant the name of the PK column in the insert statement. The last ID off the database is not a problem. The problem is getting this ID into my DataTable: When I set the value of the first column in the last row to the newest Id. This value isn't saved in the DataTable.

Comment: @VeeWee: ok, that's an another issue. This issue u can find in topics related to working with dataset in disconnected mode

Comment: The strange thing is: in the row_updated function, the connection is open. So it's not in disconnected mode? I changed the adaptar: adapt.AcceptChangesDuringFill = true;
adapt.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
And normally after the updated Event, the function AcceptChanges is called. 
So when I change the datatable, the changes have to be saved, or not?
I don't understand why the ID isn't placed in the first column of the last row and I don't seem to find the answer on internet. 
Strange :)

Comment: @VeeWee: I dont know whether i am right or now as i never used this way to work on database. Try to use cmd.Update() before calling AcceptChanges. SInce I feel as if this step will notify that cmd has request for update.

Comment: I posted the solution I found. Now the cmd isn't linked with the update command. Those 2 commands are now 2 different connections. Glad it finally works!! Thx for the help!